# Executables in /bin and /usr/bin are not found in path

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

Somehow I can’t execute files in `/bin` or `/usr/bin` without providing the full path.

This isn’t happening when running from Terminal, but, for example, iTerm can’t run `bash` (only `/bin/bash`), OnyX can't run `sw_vers`.

```
.profile: export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH 
.profile: export PATH=$PATH 
.bash_history: export PATH="$PATH:"'/Users/gilstrauss/Applications/CrossOver.app/Contents/SharedSuppor‌​t/CrossOver/bin' 
.bash_history: export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH 
.bash_history: export PATH=${PATH}:/bin 
.bash_profile: export PATH=/bin:$PATH 
.bashrc: export PATH=${PATH}:/bin:/usr/bin
```

Comment: What does this command return: `grep PATH= .profile .bash*` ?

Comment: .profile:export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH
.profile:export PATH=$PATH
.bash_history:export PATH="$PATH:"'/Users/gilstrauss/Applications/CrossOver.app/Contents/SharedSupport/CrossOver/bin'
.bash_history:export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
.bash_history:export PATH=${PATH}:/bin
.bash_profile:export PATH=/bin:$PATH
.bashrc:export PATH=${PATH}:/bin:/usr/bin

Comment: @user49204 - show that info by editing the question - and when saved check that the formatting makes it understandable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Terminal.app* correctly starting the shell does’t mean much: it runs `/usr/bin/login` (with the full path) by default, which invokes your default shell (again: defined with a full path) as an **interactive login shell** (which  will in turn read both `.profile` and `.bashrc` and leave you with a working `$PATH`). Your problem is **non-interactive shells**, which do neither, do not get any `$PATH` settings. That seems to point to OS X’ default path settings having somehow been clobbered.

To check this, run `cat /etc/paths`. The output should (at the very least) be

```
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

(these are the defaults on a pristine OS X install). If the first two are missing, you have your cause – and an easy solution:

```
mv /etc/paths /etc/paths.old # if you want to keep the current contents
def_paths=(/usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin)
for p in ${def_paths[@]}; do echo $p >> /etc/paths; done
cat /etc/paths.old >> /etc/paths # append previous contents
```

Note that as `/etc/paths` is owned by `root`, you will have to `sudo su` for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how it happened but your `PATH` went haywire, luckily it's an easy fix. Run the following in Terminal (or iTerm) to fix the issue:

```
echo "export PATH=$PATH:/bin:/usr/bin" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

This will add `/bin` and `/usr/bin` to the end of your `PATH` for this and all future terminal sessions.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't seems to solve the problem. I don't see that problem in a terminal but only when 3rd party apps tries to invoke access executables under /bin or /usr/bin.

Comment: Can you give me an example of the third party trying to access these binaries?

Comment: Yes, iTerm2 fails to run bash but only /bin/bash. You don't see that behavior when running bash from terminal.

Comment: Both of OP’s problematic paths are in his (her?) `.bashrc` already (see the `grep` listing in  [the comment above](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51305/executables-in-bin-and-usr-bin-are-not-found-in-path#comment58651_51305)).

Answer (score 1):

In OS X it's launchd that sets the initial path for everything, not your terminal files.

Now, on an unrelated note, I just found out that in OS X

```
ps -E
```

will show the environment that the process has been given. I'm sure everybody knew this except for me,but I'm very excited! Why?

Because now I can provide a partial answer.

```
ps -EA
```

Will show you the environment that every process started whether said process has a controlling terminal or not. You should see

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Which is what you should also get when you type in

```
/bin/launchctl getenv PATH
```

since launchd sets the path. It is here where your problem lies, I feel, not in your dotfiles. You might find reading the manpage for `environ(7)` as well as `path_helper(8)` useful. When the system is working properly, every app you run should have the same environment given it by launchd. The fact that Onyx is malfunctioning means that it's not shell issue, but rather a system one.

It's very important launchctl/launchd is setting the path correctly.

Comment: Thanks tons.  It is interesting to see that my Bash terminal process was launched with a plain 'PATH=/usr/bin:/bin' path.   My '/bin/launchctl getenv PATH' returns nothing on Yosemite.

Comment: What that means is that your path is being set by login(1). "The sequence of directories, separated by colons, searched by
                csh(1), sh(1), system(3), execvp(3), etc, when looking for an
                executable file.  PATH is set to ``/usr/bin:/bin'' initially
                by login(1)."

Answer (score 0):

do you have a `.bash_profile`?  in mine

```
$ cat bash_profile 

source ~/.bashrc
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin

$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/julia:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/usr/texbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin
```

(for macports to the path). It stands to reason that you could just have in .bash_profile the line

`export PATH=$PATH:/bin:/usr/bin`

And see how it goes. My guess is that you must have done something very serious to your machine, so do make a backup of your files, and test for software and also hardware soundness.